# Scraping with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im trying to dip my toes into the world of selenium and im having issues understanding how things work.

to start with im just trying to learn to scrape sites.

take this website for instance

https://udemycoupons.me/

i want to be able to scrape all of the available coupons and return: title, date, url link.

Now i can do this in BeautifulSoup using

```
search_coupon = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'td_module_1 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack'})

for coupon in search_coupon:
    coupon_title = coupon.find('h3',{'class':'entry-title td-module-title'}).text
    coupon_date = coupon.find('span',{'class':'td-post-date'}).text
    coupon_url = coupon.find('a').get('href')
    print(coupon_title, coupon_date, coupon_url)
```

How do i do this with selenium?

I cant seem to retrieve objects i the same way

Help !! :)

Comment: Note: This website is fake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use selenium for browser automation,

First, you'll need to download either [chromedriver.exe](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) or [geckodriver.exe](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) for firefox and save it to some location.

Second, create a variable to hold the browser webdriver path, like, `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')`

Third, define empty lists to hold data for each attribute you're scraping from the web. Something like this, `coupon_title=[] #List to store coupon title`. Reason is, if your interested to save this data later into a dataframe for further analysis.

A minimal reproducible example is given below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

coupon_title=[] #List to store coupon title
coupon_date=[] #List to store coupon date
coupon_url=[] #List to store coupon url

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/temp/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://udemycoupons.me/")
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
soup.prettify()
search_coupon = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'td_module_1 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack'})

for coupon in search_coupon:
    coupon_title = coupon.find('h3',{'class':'entry-title td-module-title'}).text
    coupon_date = coupon.find('span',{'class':'td-post-date'}).text
    coupon_url = coupon.find('a').get('href')
    print(coupon_title, coupon_date, coupon_url)
```

Results are:

> Harvard Free Courses Online | 65 Free Courses April 26, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/harvard-free-course-online/ 750 Free Udemy
>   Course | Apr 2020 Updated April 13, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/750-free-udemy-course-apr-2020-updated/ 100%
>   Free Udemy Coupon | How to Make Money on TikTok May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-free-udemy-coupon-how-to-make-money-on-tiktok/
>   100% Free | JSON – Quick Introduction to JSON Data JavaScript... May
>   24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-free-json-quick-introduction-to-json-data-javascript-using-json/
>   100% Free Udemy Coupon | Complete social media marketing May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-free-udemy-coupon-complete-social-media-marketing/
>   100% OFF Udemy Coupon | Digital Strategy Success 2020 May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-digital-strategy-success-2020/ 100%
>   OFF | Time Series Analysis and Forecasting using Python May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/time-series-analysis-and-forecasting-using-python-100-off/
>   100% OFF | Tools for Working From Home – Google Apps,... May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-tools-for-working-from-home-google-apps-trello-zoom/
>   100% OFF | Machine Learning Basics: Logistic Regression, LDA & KNN...
>   May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/machine-learning-basics-logistic-regression-lda-knn-in-r/
>   100% OFF | CNN for Computer Vision with Keras and TensorFlow... May
>   24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-cnn-for-computer-vision-with-keras-and-tensorflow-in-python/
>   100% OFF | Machine Learning: Logistic Regression, LDA & K-NN in... May
>   24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/logistic-regression-lda-k-nn-in-python-machine-learning-100-off/
>   100% OFF | Complete Machine Learning with R Studio – ML... May 24,
>   2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-complete-machine-learning-with-r-studio-ml-for-2020/
>   100% OFF | Adobe Premiere Pro: Video Editing for Beginners May 24,
>   2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-adobe-premiere-pro-ultimate-beginner-course/
>   100% OFF | Python for beginners – Learn all the basics... May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-python-for-beginners-learn-all-the-basics-of-python/
>   100% OFF Udemy Coupon | A Guide To Learn Angular From... May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-udemy-coupon-learn-angular/ 100% OFF
>   Udemy Coupon | The Python Course 2020! May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-udemy-coupon-the-python-course-2020/
>   100% OFF Udemy Coupon | The Data Science Course 2020 May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-udemy-coupon-the-data-science-course-2020/
>   100% OFF | How To Make Games with Gamemaker Studio 2... May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-how-to-make-games-with-gamemaker-studio-2-using-gml/
>   100% OFF | Python required for Data Science and Machine Learning...
>   May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-python-required-for-data-science-and-machine-learning-2020/
>   100% OFF Udemy Coupon | Learn Microsoft OneDrive May 24, 2020
>   https://udemycoupons.me/100-off-udemy-coupon-learn-microsoft-onedrive/

Hope this helps.

Comment: So your mixing beautiful soup and selenium. Say I wanted to log into Udemy and add the free course yo my account, would I need to log in everytime I access the pages? Reason I ask is selenium loads a fresh page each time you run

Comment: @MartynBell Beautiful and Selenium are two distinct entities. If you care to read the documentation of [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) it categorically states, *Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.* It plays no role in opening/accessing a webpage. And for this reason alone Selenium exists. I hope this should answer your doubt.

Comment: Hopefully one last question on this.

at the bottom of the items im trying to collect is a next page button.
i think the class name is "td-icon-menu-right"

but when i put

`next_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name("td-icon-menu-right").click()`
i get an error message 
`element not interactable`
where am i going wrong here?

Comment: @MartynBell thats a good Q you asked. The way I see this Q is that it can have many possible solutions. From a beginner perspective, I can think of clicking on the `next page` button. But if I hit a snag like yours, then I'll think of alternative. Before the next button it has numbered buttons like `1`,`2` etc. O clicking them individually, I see a common url like, `https://udemycoupons.me/page/2/`, `https://udemycoupons.me/page/3/` . Then I also see the maximum number of pages as `Page 1 of 179`. So think how you'll solve it? If you cant figure it out, **ASK a new Q** and I'll answer it.

Answer (score 1):

you can start with:

```
# Definning some basic functions for later usage
def clickOnId(id):
    browser.find_element_by_id(id).click()

def clickOnXpath(xpath):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

def clickOnClass(class_name):
    browser.find_element_by_class_name(class_name).click()

def TypeInId(id,toBeTyped):
    elems = browser.find_elements_by_id(id)
    elems[0].send_keys(toBeTyped)

def TypeInXpath(xpath,toBeTyped):
    elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    elems[0].send_keys(toBeTyped)
```

and also take a look at [this](https://github.com/alifzl/Whenever-there-is-an-SSH-there-is-a-way/blob/master/Step%201%20-%20Data%20Collecting/cma_data_collector.py) code for getting into selenium.